# php require statement not working when uploaded to host

Tags: php, path, require

I have a php file that lives /php/dbtest.php

it worked perfectly fine on my local machine, running xampp  I have uploaded it onto a Linux webhost,  now the line

```
require '/../app/start.php'
```

I have tried echoing error_get_last() but it returns nothing.  I am unsure what the problem is or where to look next I have tried without the forward slash.  All help very much appreciated

Comment: Check the server logs.

Comment: Turn on error reporting http://www.phptherightway.com/#errors_and_exceptions

Comment: just looked at the logs in the cpanel and they are empty

Comment: You need require('start.php');

Comment: ok getting the error Warning: require(/../app/start.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cphullsantarun/public_html/php/dbTest.php on line 23       /app/start.php exists and worked fine on local machine

Comment: I tried with () no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link should be not good. Because with the first /, you make reference to the root directoy of your linux system and generally website are contain in /etc/www. So try :

```
require '../app/start.php'
```

or something that is more linked to the way your document are present in your system.

Comment: Try to echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; in your file. It will give you the docuemtn path that you are in. After it will be esaier to find which path you search.

Comment: that returned /home/cphullsantarun/public_html

Comment: I suppose that your directori public_html is on the same root than your app directory. So that should work : require '/home/cphullsantarun/app/start.php'. Without knowledge of you directory structure is more guess than real answer.

Comment: I was just testing that path as you said yes that sorted it,  however now I have a whole host of paths that will need altering thanks.  shouldn't ../app take you up a level and then into the app folder?